# Django DRF, changing authentication schemes from JWT to basic token

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I have a Django app that was originally using drf token authentication. Everything was working perfectly.  Then I decided to switch to JWT's.  I made all the changes and everything was working perfectly.  I changed a bunch of code, updated my git and all that, then decided that the drf token auth actually was the better choice.  So I changed the authentication classes back, and removed the JWT-specific urls, but every postman request still gives me the JWT denied message: `"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."`

It seems that something internally is not being reset by just changing the authentication classes back.  I deleted my sqlite file and ran both `makemigrations` and `migrate` but still I get the same error.  How can I fix this without checking out the old branch of my git (which would lose a bunch of changes I made to the app)?

Here is the relevant section of my settings file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'prototype',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Comment: How are you sending the requests through postman? For jwt auth, you were probably sending the Authorization header like this: Authorization: Bearer {tokenvalue} For DRF token auth, you need to send them like this: Authorization: Token {tokenvalue}. Maybe you forgot to switch those?

Comment: Both the JWT and the basic token auth used the "Bearer Token" setting on postman.  With JWT I had to request a JWT from a url then use the token I got back, and with basic token I am just copying the token from the django admin page.  As far as I know nothing should need to be changed.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication as stated in the documentation here, DRF's TokenAuthentication expects authorization hedaer like this: Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b

Comment: I was mistaken in my previous comment (now deleted).  Postman automatically uses 'Bearer' and I needed 'Token'.  Thank you for the help.